# Success callback of Firebase Login not invoking

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented routes, `AuthGuard` and `Firebase` login in my project and i am using `callbacks` to listen the success and failure of `Firebase` login and act accordingly.

```
successCallback(signInSuccessData) {
    console.log("Received with Success!");
}

errorCallback(errorData) {
    console.log("Login Failed!");
}
```

However the customised callbacks of [firebaseui-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseui-angular) are working properly for Anonymous, Email and Google login, as tested here. (Check console for callbacks)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgcgn1

But when I added `AuthGuard`, `AuthService` and redirect parameters to the same, it's only responding to Google signIn. (Click on any route and it is supposed to redirect accordingly after login, Check console). I mean it's logging me in but the callbacks are not being called which were supposed to redirect user to it's page after successful login.

https://stackblitz.com/github/sizilkrishna/app-angular-onlinetools

This is how i am redirecting user after login,

```
 returnUrl: string;

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      retUrl => {
        this.returnUrl = retUrl.returnUrl || '/';
        console.log("You are set to redirected to " + this.returnUrl);
      }
    );
  }

  successCallback(signInSuccessData) {
    console.log("Child Callback, Logged in! Redirecting to " + this.returnUrl);
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
  }

  errorCallback(errorData) {
    console.log("Login failure!");

  }
```

Kindly guide me for this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your angular code not the firebase-ui npm package. If you remove the `*ngIf="!afAuth.auth.currentUser"` from the div in your login.component.html then you will see that the callback "successCallback(signInSuccessData)" gets called after successfull login with email .

Comment: That settled it, so simple yet so entagled.